# Why are 5.2% of the tokens not attended to in the fallback plan?

Tags: token-registration, ethereum

It's good to know that [B1 and Scatter](https://twitter.com/Get_Scatter/status/996557346691342336) are working hard to ensure that no EOS token holder is disappointed after the mainnet launch.

I curious to know why [5.2% of the tokens are not considered/eligible](https://eosauthority.com/genesis) for this fallback plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says on the website [EOS Authority](https://eosauthority.com/genesis)

> **Why didn't fallback get to 100%?** A bit complicated. Ethereum public
>   keys are only on-chain if an address has an outgoing transaction. Not
>   all addresses have outgoing transactions